# My child class's method not get called when initialised as Base

Tags: c#

Think my understanding about OO is wrong.

Say I have these classes

```
public class BaseValidator{
   public Result Validate(BaseRequest r){
           xxxx
     }
}
public class BaseRequest{
}
```

Then in my child class, I have this:

```
Public class ChildValidator : BaseValidator{
   public Result Validate(ChildRequest r){
           xxxx,
           base.Validate(r);
     }
}
public class ChildRequest: BaseRequest{
}
```

When using the classes:

```
BaseValidator cr = new ChildValidator();
ChildRequest r = new ChildRequest();
cr.Validate(r);
```

I thought this will call `ChildValidator`'s `Validate` method, but turned out it calls `BaseValidator`'s method.

What is the right way to do this? I want to pass my `ChildValidator` to another method, which takes `BaseValidator` as a parameter.

Comment: In base class method should have virtual keyword and in derived class method should be have override keywork

Comment: @ArjunVachhani: That won't work as-written, because the parameter types are the same. It's probably worth making the validator generic in the type of request it's expected to receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently casting `ChildValidator` to `BaseValidator`, as such you are calling `BaseValidator.Validate(BaseRequest)` which at present has a different signature to `ChildValidator.Validate(ChildRequest)`. You can pass an instance of `ChildRequest` to either method without issue because it inherits from `BaseRequest`.

Without this cast you would call `ChildValidator.Validate()` as you are expecting:

```
ChildValidator cr = new ChildValidator();
ChildRequest r = new ChildRequest();
cr.Validate(r); // Calls ChildValidator.Validate() method
```

If you want the `ChildValidator.Validate()` method to always be called then you would need to use a virtual / override method. You can't do that as your classes are currently written because you are accepting different parameter types (`BaseRequest` and `ChildRequest`).

### Interfaces

You could utilise interfaces to help you out in this case, as shown below:

```
public interface IValidator {
    bool Validate(IRequest r);
}
public class BaseValidator : IValidator {
    public virtual bool Validate(IRequest r) {
        return true;
    }
}
public class ChildValidator : BaseValidator {
    public override bool Validate(IRequest r) {
        return base.Validate(r);
    }
}

public interface IRequest { }
public class ChildRequest : BaseRequest { }
public class BaseRequest : IRequest { }
```

With the above classes / interfaces the original calls would work as follows:

```
BaseValidator cr = new ChildValidator(); // cast to BaseValidator
ChildRequest r = new ChildRequest();
cr.Validate(r); // Still calls ChildValidator.Validate() method
```

### Generic Class

Alternatively, and as Jon Skeet pointed towards, you may want to look at implementing a generic Validator class. That could perhaps look something like the below:

```
public class Validator<T> where T : BaseRequest {
    public bool Validate(T r) {
        return true;
    }
}
public class BaseRequest { }
public class ChildRequest : BaseRequest { }
```

You can use that as below:

```
var validator = new Validator<ChildRequest>();
ChildRequest request = new ChildRequest();
validator.Validate(r);
```

The best method for you will depend on the rest of your implementation and what the methods are doing.

Comment: I changed it to interface, thanks